# Connection String Security C#

Tags: c#, connection-string

i create a c# program that use mysql to verify user login.I googled about connection string security and every thing was about web.config file.
Is that necessary to hide connection string in pure c# program?if yes, please give me reference to do that.

I encrypt my code, is that enough to protect connection string in my program?

```
private static MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection("sample connection string");
```

tiny edit after solve the problem:
I find goof article and project to encrypt `App.config` designed for connection string that you can check it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/598863/EncryptionplusDecryptionplusConnectionplusStringpl)

Comment: What method are you using to encrypt your code, and why do you assume that it's insecure?

Comment: I generally use `Integrated Security` (uses the process' Windows account to pass as the credential) when at all possible. This makes it so I don't have to be concerned with securing my connection strings as tightly.

Comment: im still new with programming, and thought when program is running somebody can see connection string even if program code is encrypt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer [Securing Connection Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(VS.80).aspx).

> you should encrypt the configuration file so that the user name and
> password are not exposed in clear text.

So putting the connection string in the config file and encryting it is one way to make your connection string secure.

> **Encrypt Configuration Files**
>
> You can also store connection strings in configuration files, which
> eliminates the need to embed them in your application's code.
> Configuration files are standard XML files for which the .NET
> Framework has defined a common set of elements. Connection strings in
> configuration files are typically stored inside the
>  element in the app.config for a Windows
> application, or the web.config file for an ASP.NET application.

MSDN Reference:

- [Protecting Connection Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How To: Secure Connection Strings when Using Data Source
  Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178372.aspx)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587