# ASP.NET Core: Where to place Connection String for Production

Tags: c#, sql-server, macos, asp.net-core-mvc, connection-string

ASP.Net Core, using version 5.0.100, and I am trying to publish my web application to a hosting provider. I am trying to figure out where to place my connection string. As of right now I have it inside `appsetting.json`.

```
"ConnectionString": {
    "default": "data source=.; database= myDataBase; user id =    sa; password = myPassw0rd",
  }
```

Is this bad practice? I am worried that someone may find the connection string and hack the website. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

There are several places you can put your connection string:

- Settings files, such as appsettings.json
- Environment variables
- Azure Key Vault
- Azure App Configuration
- Command-line arguments
- Custom providers, installed or created
- Directory files
- In-memory .NET objects

See the documentation for [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for configuration for all of the above. Each option carries different kinds of risk, so you'll need to evaluate which one makes the most sense for your use case.

Comment: I implemented environment variables on my web application: macOS. This may be a dumb question as I am just getting started, but do all hosting providers offer environment variables? I want to use HostGator, but I am not sure if they offer asp.net core environment variables.

Comment: I can't speak for HostGator but I expect that all hosting providers provide a way to set environment variables.

Comment: from the 3 well-known shared hosting providers that i dealt with non of them provide any way to set environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you're questioning how to best manage connection strings. Storing credentials in any configuration file like appsettings.json and web.config is a bad idea. There are a number of ways to protect your secrets. It really comes down to your specific use case.  My preferred method is using Application Pool Identities.  Here a a few resources to get you started.

[Connection String Security C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259587/connection-string-security-c-sharp)

[Protecting Connection Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/protecting-connection-information?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[Application Pool Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)